# How to use date filter with MuleSoft OData (version 2.0)

Tags: odata, raml, mulesoft

I am using MuleSoft (3.9) OData (2.0) RAML and passing query to an Oracle database. Adding date filter in the url
`&$filter=START_DATE le datetime'2016-01-01T11:00:00'` throws database error:

> SQL command not properly ended.

How can date filter be added to OData RAML?

The database query is being generated as `select....where START_DATE <= datetime'2016-01-01T11:00:00'`. Do we need to explicitly convert using `to_date`?

Answer (score 0):

Use below variable to parse OData filter to SQL filter

```
%var odataFilterToSQLFilter = (odataFilter) -> 

    (( odataFilter replace "eq null" with "is null" 
     replace "ne null" with "is not null" 
     replace " eq " with " = " 
     replace " ne " with " != " 
     replace " gt " with " > " 
     replace " lt " with " < " 
     replace " ge " with " >= " 
     replace " le " with " <= " 
     replace " and " with " AND " 
     replace " or " with " OR " ) splitBy " " map  (
         ("TO_DATE('" ++ (($ replace "datetime'" with "" ) replace "T" with " ") ++ ",'yyyy-MM-dd HH24:MI:SS')") when $ as :string contains "datetime" otherwise $
     )) joinBy " "

%var toSQLWhere = (odataFilter) -> (" WHERE " ++ odataFilterToSQLFilter(odataFilter)) unless odataFilter == null otherwise ""

---
"SELECT " ++ generateSqlFields(filters.select) ++ " FROM $remoteEntityName"
 ++ ( 
    (toSQLWhere(filters.filter))
```